# Using v-for and v-show to hide/show additional text inside an p element

Tags: vue.js

I have this html code

```
<tr v-for="(help, index) in helps">
    <td scope="row">{{ help.ID }}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{ help.Date | formatDateWithTime }}</td>
    <td>
        <p @click="fullTextFun(index)" v-show="help.FullText">{{ help.Text.substring(0,16) + '...' }}</p>
        <p @click="fullTextFun(index)" v-show="!help.FullText">{{ help.Text }}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to show the full text when someone click on the current `p` element. This is my vue function

```
fullTextFun: function(index) {
    this.helps[index].FullText = !this.helps[index].FullText;
},
```

It doesn't work. I also tried to do it using this code

```
<span @click="fullTextFun(help)" v-show="help.FullText">{{ help.Text.substring(0,16) + '...' }}</span>
fullTextFun: function(item) {
    item.FullText = !item.FullText;
},
```

But again without any luck. It seems the `v-show` function don't care about the status of `help.FullText`

**When I load the data I don't have `FullText` variable in my `helps` array. I don't know if this is the problem**

This is what it is inside my `helps` variable when first loaded

> [{"ID":"2","Date":"2019-05-15
>   17:27:29","Text":"randomText"},{"ID":"4","Date":"2019-05-17
>   09:53:59","Text":"some text"}]

Comment: In your v-for you call the variable "helps" ```v-for="(help, index) in helps"``` but you array is called ```help```

Comment: @Jalil, yes it was a typo. My variable with the array is called `helps`

Comment: It's also because you dont have the ```FullText``` variable in the helps array, you need to call it as just ```Text```

Comment: Have you tried adding `FullText` to the entries in the `helps` array?

Comment: Have you tried `v-if` instead of `v-show` ? And have you tried to debug it with watch ? If watch cannot detect your changes, then you have a reactivity issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be Vue reactivity issue.

```
fullTextFun: function(index) {
    this.helps[index].FullText = !this.helps[index].FullText;
    this.helps = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.helps))
}
```

Basically Vue only updates if you change the reference.
When you update `this.helps[index].FullText`, `this.helps` still points to old object reference, and Vue can't recognize the change.

Another solution is using Vue.set

```
Vue.set(this.helps[index], 'FullText', !this.helps[index].FullText)
```

You can read more at [Vue document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: that worked, but can you please explain in your answer why your code is working and mine it is not?

Comment: pls use `Vue.set` instead and avoid using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`, it's really slow. See https://medium.com/ft-product-technology/this-one-line-of-javascript-made-ft-com-10-times-slower-5afb02bfd93f

Comment: my experience is to use vuex with a computed property, never had problems with array there ...

Comment: How does that work if ```FullText``` is never created?

Comment: I suppose `this.helps[index]` is an object, then `this.helps[index].fullText` is undefined. Then `!this.helps[index].fullText` will get false value, so on and so forth.

Comment: @Shuyi, can you write an example of what you mean?

Comment: ``` es6 
let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        a: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    mutations: {
        update(state, val) {
            state.a = val;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    store,
    computed: {
        a: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.a;
            },
            set(val) {
                this.$store.commit('update', val);
            }
        }
    }
});
```  
In this case, it just overwrites the entire array, and forces Vue to refresh, thus bypassing the reactivity problem